# Triggerhappy failing on 64 bit Bookworm on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I am testing the new Bookworm 64 bit https://downloads.raspberrypi.com/raspi ... 023-12-06/ on Raspberry Pi 4B.

During boot, the triggerhappy udev rule is failing and board doesn't boot up.

Steps:

1. Installed Bookworm (64 bit) using Raspberry Pi Imager on uSD card.
2. Added `enable_uart=1` to `config.txt`
3. Powered on the Pi.

Boot log:

```
Starting kernel ...

[    8.919929] (udev-worker)[376]: input0: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' terminated by signal TERM.
[    8.933400] (udev-worker)[365]: input1: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' terminated by signal TERM.
[    8.934729] (udev-worker)[376]: input0: Failed to wait for spawned command '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev': Input/output error
[    8.946898] (udev-worker)[365]: input1: Failed to wait for spawned command '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev': Input/output error
[    8.960724] (udev-worker)[376]: input0: Failed to execute '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev', ignoring: Input/output error
[    8.975075] (udev-worker)[365]: input1: Failed to execute '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev', ignoring: Input/output error
[    9.141737] reboot: Power down
```

On 32bit Bookworm I don't get this error and booting works fine.

Can anyone please help me to troubleshoot this and how to fix it?